# Getting "Aspect ratio constraints with Xcode versions prior to 5.1" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Just upgraded to recent Xcode 5.1 version and accidentally found cool feature in storyboards - pin two elements vertically and keeping aspect ratio between of them. However, getting an error during the compilation. Then I read [Xcode release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/xc5_release_notes/xc5_release_notes.html) about this new feature but still it's unclear - is it supported for iOS7.1 only (was unable to find in specs) or other things need to be done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we open Storyboard then go to the right pane under the File Inspector tab, then we will find a section called Interface Builder Document. This section contains "Buid for" drop down list and so setting it to Xcode 5.1 fixes the problem. This setting manages storyboard file structure and minimum supported Xcode version.